How can I build an accurate dataset in a short span of time?
We are developing an iOS app that lets users send customizable digital cards. Users can choose from various card templates, enter their own text, and make edits to the card as they like. We also have a feature where users can provide a short message, like "happy birthday mom," and receive an expanded version of the text, such as "happy birthday to my special mother! I love you and hope you have an amazing day."
I'm conducting research to figure out how to accomplish this and planning to create a model using Natural Language Processing (NLP) and CoreML. However, I've encountered an issue in finding a suitable dataset for this particular task. As a result, I'm interested in building an accurate dataset specifically tailored to this purpose. However, I'm unsure where I can obtain the necessary data or if there are alternative data sources available for quick use.
If you have any insights or alternative methods to achieve this feature, please share them.

Although readily available datasets on this exact topic might be missing, you can try to scrape existing digital postcard websites. As an example, you can try to develop a scrapper to search for "birthday postcard text" on Google and extract the text from the top 20 websites. You can refer to this guide to get started with scraping in Python.
If you are still interested in curating your own dataset, keep in mind the following steps and make sure you have sufficient expertise in your team to get the best out of this data since dataset creation is very extensive:

Clearly define the purpose of your datase that fuels your drive and enables you to reach your goals

Identify the key variables or characteristics related to your purpose that you will be collecting data on. For example, if your case can be about the relationship between occasion (e.g. birthday, wedding) and postcard text, your variables would be occasion and postcard text.

Make a plan for how you will gather the data, including the method (surveys, observations, etc.), number of participants needed, how you will select participants, and the tool you'll use.

Gather the first batch of data following your plan in iterations.

Review the first collected data carefully, fixing any errors and removing duplicates. Organize it neatly. Then iterate over this gathering and reviewing steps until a sufficient amount of data is collected.


You can also refer to the following guidelines:
https://www.data-mania.com/blog/creating-datasets/
https://towardsdatascience.com/the-definite-guide-for-creating-an-academic-level-dataset-with-industry-requirements-and-6db446a26cb2
https://pcsocial.medium.com/how-to-create-a-dataset-a-comprehensive-step-by-step-interactive-guide-c1271a5f18e5
